# ……………we have traveled 500 miles - Fill in the blank

Tags: grammar

Could someone please tell me which choice fits the best in the following example:

> ……………we have traveled 500 miles.
>
> a) so far 
>   b) up to here 
>  c) until here 
>  d) by here

I think only “a” and “b” work in this context.

Comment: only "a" works in this context.

Comment: Thanks @jim, but I wonder if you could explain it why it is like that? Why the others do not work in this context?

Comment: I thought more about this and this seems tricky. Deleting mine one. Rewriting it in a while.

Comment: @MaulikV I really appreciate your attention, but I wished everything was so simple as you see my friend. ;) (just kidding) When I submit a new topic, doubtlessly I carefully think about it, analyze various aspects of it (as far as my literacy lets me) and then if I cannot find a relative topic, which can be responsive to my question, then I send it to the forum. Let's sometimes think twice about some topics. ;)

Comment: Other than *by*, all (though forcefully, unnaturally?) can be fit in that! I'm finding some concrete source to justify that... :)

Comment: These questions would be better if you explained why instead of just asking us to do homework problems.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, I think only a) is normally used.

> **So far,** we have travelled 500 miles.

It's not really a fixed distance because it's implied you are still travelling further.

b) up to here - may be OK in some contexts but it usually refers to fixed distances/locations, as in:

> Please fill the bottle **up to here**.

c) until here - this is not correct, because *until* is usually used for time, not distance/locations:

> I will work **until 5:30**.

d) by here - *by* can be used for a lot of things, but not distance measurements or location points, as far as I am aware. Can't think of a example using *by here* offhand.

b) *up to here* might be OK if you are referring to points on a map.
You could say something similar:

> **Up to this point,** we have traveled 500 miles.

Comment: Thanks @user3169, but one more question:
Did you mean just because the sentence implies "we are still travelling further" and there is no any implication of a fixed distance, I have to use "so far" or there is another reason which I have to know? Would you please interpret this sentence using both "so far" and "up to now". :)
Actually I know already why the other choices do not work, but don't know why "a" works!

Comment: @A-friend,  "So far" works because it provides a grammatically correct, well understood sentence while the others are not as good for various reasons.  But it's the phrase "So far" that directs the meaning that "we are still travelling further". Another possible context could be, "As ordered, we have traveled 500 miles.  We are now setting up base camp.  Awaiting further instruction."  But well-structured options like this are not available, so this meaning is not available.

Comment: @A-friend Yes, as CoolHandLouis explained. And if you said "Up to now, we have travelled 500 miles.", its technically OK, but again "now" really refers to a position at a point in time. It implies that you stopped even momentarily at where you were "now". And there is no implication of further action.

Comment: Thanks a million guys. And (possibly) my question: ( ;) )
- …………….we have traveled 500 miles.
a) So far
b) Up to now
c) By now
d) Until now

Answer (score 0):

a) "so far" would be the best choice if you are in the act of travleing and have not reached your destination.  Yes, there is an implication that there is more distance to go.

b) "up to here" and d) "by here" can be use but they imply an indirect reference the distance.  For example, if you are pointing to a location on a map, you could say "Up to here, we've have traveled 500 miles."  "here" refering to the spot on the map, not where you are physically even thought they might be the same place.

c) "until" is related to time so would not be appropriate.

Comment: thanks, but 'c' is "by now" not "until now" which is 'd'. So I wonder if you correct our post in the way I could understand what you're getting at.
Thanks

Comment: In the original post it's still "c) until here".  Did you edit?  I don't see "by now" at all.

Comment: No. Of course I didn't. I made and posted a new question having different settings, but related to the original post.
I just though you were answering my new question:
 …………….we have traveled 500 miles. a) So far b) Up to now c) By now d) Until now
Then I wonder if you answer this question too.

Comment: Oh..no, my answer is based on the original post: a) so far b) up to here c) until here d) by here

Answer (score 0):

Option d) doesn't work at all. Option b), and at a strain c), could fit, but would convey a slightly different meaning from the most natural sounding of them all a), in that the 'here' part and the '500 miles' both refer to distance, whereas in a) 'so far' can be taken be taken as an implicit reference to some amount of time, and therefore carry connotations of distance over time, i.e. speed of progress.

So, perhaps:

up to here (Shrewsbury) we have traveled 500 miles towards Land's End

versus:

so far (day 6) we have traveled 500 miles towards Land's End

Comment: do you mean it sounds multivocally iin this specific sentence or using "so far" would be ambiguous in all similar contexts?